# why can get address of member function by class type

Tags: c++, bind, pointer-to-member

I met this code:

```
 auto f3 = std::bind(&Foo::print_sum, &foo, 95, _1);
```

in the previous code, we can apply the address operator to a member function while there is no instance 
object been created, how can that be possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type system of C++ contains a lesser-known category of types which are *pointers to members*. Given any class type `C` and any object or function type `T`, there is a pointer-to-member type `T C::*`. Values of these types can be obtained by applying the address-of operator to the qualified name of a class member. For example:

```
 struct Foo;

 int Foo::* pi;                  // C = Foo, T = int
 void (Foo::* pf)(bool, int);    // C = Foo, T = void(bool, int)

 struct Foo {
     int a;
     int b;
     void f(bool, int);
     void g(bool, int);
 };

 pi = &Foo::a;
 pf = &Foo::f;
```

The member pointer itself only selects a class member abstractly, unrelated to any class *instance*. To actually *use* the pointer, you need a class instance, and the member-dereference operator `.*`:

```
Foo x;

int n = x.*pi;     // gets x.a
(x.*pf)(true, n);  // calls x.f(true, n)

pf = &Foo::g;
(x.*pf)(true, n);  // calls x.g(true, n)
```

(The parentheses in the call expression through the pointer-to-member `pf` are necessary because otherwise the expression `a.*b(c)` means `a.*(b(c))`. This is occasionally a point of confusion for new users.)

Don't confuse a pointer-to-member to an object member with a pointer to the actual object!

```
int * p = &(x.*pi);   // p = &x.a
```

Here `p` points to the actual `int` subobject `x.a` and is an ordinary object pointer, whereas `pi` is a pointer-to-member that abstractly selects the `Foo::a` member of a `Foo` object.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the address of `Foo`'s member function gives you a pointer to member function. This type is completely independent of any `Foo` object. If you're going to actually call the function, you need to provide a `Foo` object. In this case, the `this` parameter of `Foo::print_sum` is being bound to `&foo` with `std::bind`.

Answer (score 0):

of course you need to have an instance of type `Foo` called `foo`, because the member function `Foo::print_sum` is bound to `foo` .